# Memory Error Message When Fitting Mixed-Effect Random Forest Model

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a new package in python, which is MERF (Mixed-Effect Random Forest). When I want to fit the data with 200000+ rows with a small number of clusters (<100), the model always outputs a memory error message. I think the problem lies in the number of clusters. When I used the cluster number very large (>10000), it gave a valid output.

```
from merf import MERF

merf = MERF()

clusters_train = np.array([])
for i in np.arange(len(df_train)):
    if 1570<=df_train['fss'][i]<=1875:
        clusters_train = np.append(clusters_train,1)
    elif 1510<=df_train['fss'][i]<=1569:
        clusters_train = np.append(clusters_train,2)
    elif 1450<=df_train['fss'][i]<=1509:
        clusters_train = np.append(clusters_train,3)
    elif 1340<=df_train['fss'][i]<=1449:
        clusters_train = np.append(clusters_train,4)
    elif 1001<=df_train['fss'][i]<=1339:
        clusters_train = np.append(clusters_train,5)
    else:
        clusters_train = np.append(clusters_train,0)
clusters_train = pd.Series(clusters_train)

X_train = df_train[['ccs','pydx','gbr']]

Z_train = df_train[['pct30p','pct90p']]

y_train = y_train['bad']

merf.fit(X_train, Z_train, clusters_train, y_train)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl3GV.png)

Comment: I think you'd better include the error-message plus the import statement and any code to initialize the merf instance, as well. I.e, are you doing `from merf import MERF`
followed by  `merf = MERF()` ?

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me.  `np`, `df_train` and `y_train` aren't defined.  I know how to fix the `np` one, but not the other two.

Comment: Have you tried running this code via regular Python instead of in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I only tried on Jupyter notebook. df_train is a data frame with columns: "Key1", "pct30p", "pct90p", "fss", "ccs", "pydx" and "gbr". y_train is a data frame with one column: "bad". They have the same number of rows.